# Struts Action responsible for rendering captcha does not work inside login page

Tags: java, struts2, captcha, tomcat8

I am having an issue with displaying a captcha in my login page. I use two Struts 2 actions, CaptchaAction and LoginAction. I call the CaptchaAction from *img/src* attribute using s:url struts2 tag. Here are my codes :

CaptchAction code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CaptchaAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private byte imageBytes[] = null;
    static String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$";
    private static final Pattern check = Pattern.compile(regex);
    private String charPool[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "7", "8", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
            "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "9", "0", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b",
            "c", "d", "e", "f", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s" };
    private String rndcode = "";
    private int rndNumber;
    public static final String CAPTCHA_KEY = "";
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Captcha Action is being executed ! ");
            response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            int width = 110;
            int height = 33;
            int fontSize = 18;
            int xGap = 12;
            int yGap = 22;
            String fontName = "Arial";
            Color gradiantStartColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;
            Color gradiantEndColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;
            Color textColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
            String[] newData = { generateRandomCode() };
            System.out.println("Data for Captcha : " + newData);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
            RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, gradiantStartColor, 0, height / 2, gradiantEndColor, true);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            for (int i = 0; i < width - 10; i = i + 25) {
                int q = Math.abs(generateSecureRandomNumber()) % width;
                int colorIndex = Math.abs(generateSecureRandomNumber()) % 200;
                g2d.setColor(new Color(colorIndex, colorIndex, colorIndex));
                g2d.drawLine(i, q, width, height);
                g2d.drawLine(q, i, i, height);
            }
            g2d.setColor(textColor);
            int index = Math.abs(generateSecureRandomNumber()) % newData.length;
            String captcha = newData[index];
            System.out.println("Actual Captcha :" + captcha);
            if (captcha != null || !captcha.isEmpty() && check.matcher(captcha).matches()) {
                session.put(CAPTCHA_KEY, captcha);
            }
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < newData[index].length(); i++) {
                Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, fontSize);
                g2d.setFont(font);
                x += xGap + (Math.abs(generateSecureRandomNumber()) % 7);
                y = yGap + Math.abs(generateSecureRandomNumber()) % 12;
                g2d.drawChars(newData[index].toCharArray(), i, 1, x, y);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            if (imageBytes != null) {
                outputStream.write(imageBytes);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Captcha Action is executed ! ");
        return NONE;
    }

    private String generateRandomCode() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        rndcode = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            rndNumber = generateSecureRandomNumber() % 50;
            rndcode = rndcode.concat(charPool[rndNumber]);
        }
        return rndcode;
    }

    public static int generateSecureRandomNumber() {
        SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = null;
        int sr = 0;
        try {
            // For windows machine
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
                secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                sr = secureRandomGenerator.nextInt(1000000);
            }
            // for Linux machine
            else {
                secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNG");
                sr = secureRandomGenerator.nextInt(1000000);
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sr;
    }
    
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    
}
```

LoginAction Code :

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import presentation.web.common.bean.UserBean;
import service.common.UserAppService;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.SkipValidation;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ServletRequestAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private UserAppService userAppService;
    private UserBean userBean;
    private String contextPath;
    private String sessionCaptcha ;
    
    

    @SkipValidation
    public String init() {
        
        this.contextPath = this.servletRequest.getContextPath();
        
        return "none";
        
    }



    @SkipValidation
    public String logout() throws Exception {
        this.session.clear();
        return "success";
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        sessionCaptcha = (String) session.get(CaptchaAction.CAPTCHA_KEY);
        if (sessionCaptcha.equals(this.userBean.getCaptcha())) {
            UserBean checkedLogin = this.userAppService.authentifier(this.userBean);

            if (checkedLogin != null) {
                this.session.put("userBean", this.userBean);
                this.session.remove("LOCKING_TIME");
                this.session.remove("NOMBRE_TENTATIVE_AUTH");
                return "success";
            }

            return "error";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }


    
    public void addActionErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
        this.userBean.setPassword("");
        addActionError(errorMsg);
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void setUserAppService(UserAppService userAppService) {
        this.userAppService = userAppService;
    }

    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        return this.userBean;
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }

    public String getContextPath() {
        return this.contextPath;
    }

    public void setContextPath(String contextPath) {
        this.contextPath = contextPath;
    }
}
```

login.jsp page :

```
<s:form theme="simple" action="login" class="text-right">

                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                                        <s:textfield id="username" name="userBean.login"
                                            class="form-control" />
                                        <s:label for="username" key="accueil.nomUtilisateur" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                                        <s:password id="password" name="userBean.password"
                                            key="accueil.motPasse" class="form-control" />
                                        <s:label for="password" key="accueil.motPasse" />
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <!-- Captcha  -->
                                    
                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                                        <s:textfield id="captcha" name="userBean.captcha"
                                            class="form-control" />
                                        <s:label for="captcha" key="accueil.captcha" />
                                        
                                        <img id="capImg" src="<s:url action="LoadCaptcha"/>" style="width:100%;"/>
                                        <!--
                                        refresh captcha : TODO
                                        <s:submit type="button" onclick="generateNewCaptcha();" value="%{getText('accueil.captcha.refresh')}"/> 
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        -->
                                         
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    

                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <s:submit cssClass="btn stylish-color-dark"
                                            value="%{getText('accueil.envoyer')}" />
                                    </div>

                                </s:form>
```

struts.xml :

```
<action name="login"
            class="web.common.action.LoginAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">ServicesInit</result>
            <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">login.jsp</result>
</action>
        
<action name="LoadCaptcha" 
                class="web.common.action.CaptchaAction">
                <result name="none">login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="ServicesInit"
            class="web.common.action.ServicesAction"
            method="init">
            <result name="none">ServicesView.jsp</result>
</action>
```

the *<s:url>* tag seems to call the LoadCaptcha Action but returns nothing but a broken image icon. Also when I inspect its element it shows that the response is *text/html* rather than *image/jpeg* like this screen capture here :
[image]
What could be the problem ?

Comment: It's not clear which response object did you inspect? Do you have any errors in the console? Post the error message with the stacktrace. In the struts.xml use a devMode=true to show errors in the log.

Comment: I already have devMode=true inside struts.xml, I have no errors inside the logs, it seems like CaptchaAction is not getting executed, because I used System.out.println() inside its execute method, and those lines did not get printed to stdout

Comment: Then the problem might be your backend isn't started or have wrong mapping. Until you define the problem it's impossible to answer to your question. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.